# Using Export Default { myNamedModule } - and then importing that named module in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, babeljs, transpiler

I've spent a while tinkering with my `Babel` configurations. I'm not an expert, but I'm also far inexperienced with `Babel`. I am pretty new to trying to configure it with regards to `React-Native` though.

I tried a lot of things to get default exports working with `React Native`, but when I try to import named modules from default exports, I get `undefined`.

What am I overlooking here? I can `export default` and then import named modules in my `Webpack` build environment. Why not in my `React Native` environment?

I believe it may be related to the absence of the `Babel` plugin `"add-module-exports"` in `React Native`, but including it breaks everything. Is there any way to include it or emulate its behavior?

Examples and `.babelrc` files below.

**myNamedModule.js**

```
export default { myNamedModule };
```

---

**Importing the module `myNamedModule`**

```
import { myNamedModule } from './myNamedModule'; // Results in undefined
```

**Importing the whole file**

```
import myNamedModule from './myNamedModule'; // Results in undefined
```

**Importing the whole file with `* as`**

```
import * as myNamedModule from './myNamedModule'; // Imports the entire default export as expected
```

---

#### **`.babelrc` for `React Native`**

```js
{
  "presets": [
    "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset",
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",
    [
      "babel-plugin-module-resolver",
      {
        "alias": {
          "react-native-vector-icons": "@expo/vector-icons"
        },
      },
    ],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { legacy: true }],
  ]
}
```

---

#### **`.babelrc` for Electron**

*(Last I checked this also worked for web if I changed `preset-env`)*

```js
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "targets": { "electron": "3.0.10" },
      "useBuiltIns": "usage"
    }],
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-flow"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types",
    "add-module-exports",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from",
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining", { "loose": false }],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-do-expressions",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-classes",
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Andrew. Unfortunately that's in the list of things I tried above and it results in undefined, which I can't understand.

Comment: I think `export default { myNamedModule };` is restricting you to load all the modules that are exported from myNamedModule. That is why you have `import * as myNamedModule from './myNamedModule'; ` working but other options are not.

Comment: @PranayTripathi that may be the case, but do you have any idea why I'd be able to import named modules using my `.babelrc` for Electron?

Comment: well my understanding is rc files are more like run command files. It probably triggers some kind of import for these modules would be my guess. thats why you see many  packages which needs resource configuration use rc files, such babel and eslint etc. Sorry m not fully aware of how rc files transform to specific imports.